# Traversing from a leaf to one or more parent in the table

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have the following `Model`:

```
SELECT m.city_area_id AS city_area_id
FROM menus m
JOIN oc_category c ON (m.id = c.menu_id)
JOIN oc_category oc ON (oc.parent_id = c.category_id)
JOIN oc_product_to_category ptc ON
    ptc.category_id = oc.category_id AND
    ptc.product_id = $dish_id
```

The expected behavior of this Model is to find the city area ID given a dish.

It works this way:

1. Find our product's [our input] category ID through the table `oc_product_to_category`.
2. Using the `category_id` from this relationship, we head over to `oc_category` to find the `parent_id` of this particular product.
3. Once you've reached the top-most category ID, there would be a `menu_id` [the `menu_id` is `0` if it's not the top-most `category_id`, and the `parent_id` would also be `0` since there will be no more parents] for us to use.
4. Once we have the `menu_id`, we will be able to find this menu's city area ID.

The following is an example of a `category_id` row that has a `parent_id`. As you can tell, the `menu_id` is `0`, and the `parent_id` is a non-zero value.

```
+-------------+-------+-----------+-----+--------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+---------+
| category_id | image | parent_id | top | column | sort_order | status | date_added          | date_modified       | visible_official | menu_id |
+-------------+-------+-----------+-----+--------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+---------+
|         784 | NULL  |       783 |   0 |      0 |          1 |      1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                1 |       0 |
+-------------+-------+-----------+-----+--------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+---------+
```

My issue:

My current SQL query works if for each `category_id`, there is only one `parent_id` level to traverse. So, for those products that have two parent `category_id`s [as opposed to one], my script would return an empty set.

My question is - how do I intelligently traverse from a leaf to the upmost parent no matter how many parents this particular category ID may have?

EDIT: Looks like my SQL row's formatting is all botched. I have no idea how to add a horizontal scrollbar to my code block =(

Comment: A leaf in a binary tree is one that does not have anything on its left and right side. `if(node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL)`

Comment: @self Hello there. Pardon my brash reply, but how does your comment have anything to do with how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, you're geting a particular set of row from `ptc` based on some criteria, e.g

```
SELECT ptc.*
  FROM oc_product_to_category ptc
 WHERE ptc.product_id = $dish_id
```

Then you want to get the related `oc`...

```
  JOIN oc_category oc 
    ON oc.category_id = ptc.category_id
```

And if that's not a top level `oc`, you want to get its parent...

```
  JOIN oc_category a1
    ON a1.category_id = oc.parent_id
```

And if that's not a top level, you want to get its parent...

```
  JOIN oc_category a2
    ON a2.category_id = a1.parent_id
```

And so on, until you get the top most parent.

One approach to doing this in a single query is to first determine the maximum possible depth of the tree, and then use outer join operations to return the parent of each level...

```
SELECT ptc.*
  FROM oc_product_to_category ptc
  JOIN oc_category a0
    ON a0.category_id = ptc.category_id
  LEFT JOIN oc_category a1 ON a1.category_id = oc.parent_id
  LEFT JOIN oc_category a2 ON a2.category_id = a1.parent_id
  LEFT JOIN oc_category a3 ON a3.category_id = a2.parent_id
  LEFT JOIN oc_category a4 ON a4.category_id = a3.parent_id
 WHERE ptc.product_id = $dish_id
```

The trick now is to determine which of those table references (a1, a2, a3, a4) returned the topmost level.

One way to do that is to use an expression that tests each of those levels, from the top down, to determine the highest level that returned a non-NULL value. For example:

```
       CASE
         WHEN a4.category_id IS NOT NULL THEN a4.menu_id
         WHEN a3.category_id IS NOT NULL THEN a3.menu_id
         WHEN a2.category_id IS NOT NULL THEN a2.menu_id
         WHEN a1.category_id IS NOT NULL THEN a1.menu_id
         WHEN a0.category_id IS NOT NULL THEN a0.menu_id
       END
```

You can use the result from that expression in the predicate for the join to the `menus` table

```
  LEFT JOIN menus m ON m.id = expr
```

So, the whole query might looks something like this:

```
SELECT m.city_area_id as city_area_id
FROM oc_product_to_category ptc
JOIN oc_category oc ON oc.category_id = ptc.category_id
LEFT JOIN oc_category a0 ON a0.category_id = oc.parent_id
LEFT JOIN oc_category a1 ON a1.category_id = a0.parent_id
LEFT JOIN oc_category a2 ON a2.category_id = a1.parent_id
LEFT JOIN oc_category a3 ON a3.category_id = a2.parent_id
LEFT JOIN oc_category a4 ON a4.category_id = a3.parent_id
LEFT JOIN menus m
    ON m.id =
        CASE
            WHEN a4.parent_id = 0 THEN a4.menu_id
            WHEN a3.parent_id = 0 THEN a3.menu_id
            WHEN a2.parent_id = 0 THEN a2.menu_id
            WHEN a1.parent_id = 0 THEN a1.menu_id
            WHEN a0.parent_id = 0 THEN a0.menu_id
        END
WHERE ptc.product_id = $dish_id
```

This example query will look only look for a topmost parent up to four levels above; if you're hierarchy has a greater depth than that, you'd need to extend this to more levels, following the same pattern...

```
  LEFT JOIN oc_category a5 ON a5.category_id = a4.parent_id
  LEFT JOIN oc_category a6 ON a6.category_id = a5.parent_id
```

And you'd need to extend the expression that return the `menu_id` to include checks whether a row was returned from those levels.

(In my implemtations, I typically use a NULL value for the `parent_id` column to indicate a topmost node. If your hierarchy is implemented differently, using a value of `0` for the parent_id, you may need to use a different expression to test for the topmost level, but the expression would follow the same pattern:

```
       CASE
         WHEN a4.parent_id = 0 THEN a4.menu_id
         WHEN a3.parent_id = 0 THEN a3.menu_id
         WHEN a2.parent_id = 0 THEN a2.menu_id
         WHEN a1.parent_id = 0 THEN a1.menu_id
         WHEN a0.parent_id = 0 THEN a0.menu_id
       END
```

Comment: From my research, the solution you provided is called an adjatency table is that correct?

Comment: Hmm. It seems like the results are returning empty regardless of the product, but I am not quite sure how to debug this query. Would you mind if we bring this to a chat?

Comment: I have made a minor edit to your 5th code block since it appears you are missing a something like `LEFT JOIN oc_category a0 ON a0.category_id = oc.parent_id`.

Comment: Looks like your solution is called an adjacency list: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back Slide 54.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: Yes, this design pattern is frequently called an adjacency list. It's likely that there are some problems in the queries, I just hacked them out and didn't test.... but they should sufficient to highlight pattern. The big drawback with this approach is that it's limited to a FINITE depth; another approach is to get the direct parent, then run another query to get that rows direct parent, and do that in a loop; that's workable (but that's more roundtrips to the database).

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: For debugging, I'd add to the SELECT list: a0.id, a2.id, a3.id, etc. to (to verify that the parent and ancestors are being returned); also add `parent_id` and the `menu_id` columns from each level, along with the expression that derives a single value for `menu_id`. (I don't understand your table structure or your data, given the `parent_id` column in the table, I took a guess as to what you were trying to achieve... it seemed like what you wanted to traverse the `parent_id` values up to the topmost level (root node).

Comment: Hi Spencer. I solved it (but forgot to update). It was xx.parent_id = 0 (which looks like you updated). Works well. Learned a lot on anti patterns while coding this, so thanks for the learning experience.

Comment: Bill Karwin's book is excellent. I'm not sure the "adjacency list" model really qualifies as an anti pattern. His comparison does point out that it allows for referential integrity to be enforced. In our shop, we do also populate a table that has all of the ancestors and dependents, populated from the adjacency list table. The tree (hierarchy) is very stable; there are infrequent node additions, node removals and reorganizations. (Our hierarchy table has very short rows... id, parent_id, and references to the actual items. All of the attributes of the items are in different tables.)

Comment: With Oracle, we can use the `SELECT ... CONNECT BY` syntax to traverse the entire tree without a finite limit on the number of levels. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support this functionality, so we emulate it with the pattern of the query in my answer. The biggest drawback (as I see it) is the finite number of levels. The query isn't really all that hard, but it is a bit repetitive; I don't think it's any harder than the code required to support inserts/reorgs/referential integrity of the nested set or path models.

Comment: I see that the lecture slide suggests alternatives to our current table schema. Which one do you think is the best one to use? I'm thinking if I am creating a website like Reddit that can contain thousands [if not multiples more] of nested comments, using an adjacency list with a finite number of levels would very quickly break things.